# DropDownListFor for enum with custom values (stored in attributes) doesn't select item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enums, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor, modelbinders

I have enum with assigned string values (in attributes) and would like to have html helper for displaying it. Unfortunately I need to use assigned values as a keys in ddl. Because of that it doesn't select item stored in ViewModel. What to do?

**Sample Enum**

```
public enum StatusEnum
{
    [Value("AA")]
    Active,

    [Value("BB")]
    Disabled
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public StatusEnum Status { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListForEnum(x => x.Status, new {})
```

**DropDownListForEnum helper**

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListForEnum<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = Enum.GetNames(typeof(TEnum))
                                            .Select(n => (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), n))
                                            .Select(e => new SelectListItem() {
                                                Text = e.ToString(),
                                                Value = EnumExtension.GetValue(e).ToString(),
                                                Selected = EnumExtension.GetValue(e) == EnumExtension.GetValue(metadata.Model)
                                            })
                                            .ToList();

    return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, items, htmlAttributes);
}
```

Comment: What version MVC are you running?

Comment: We are using version 4

Comment: What is `[Value]` and `EnumExtension.GetValue`? Your custom helper returns `htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, ...);` which means that if the value of property `Status` does not match one of the values of your options then the first option will be selected (setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is pointless). If `EnumExtension.GetValue` returns `AA` or `BB` then its not going to bind on post back anyway (unless you have created a custom model binder) so not sure what the point of this is.

Comment: Yes, EnumExtension.GetValue returns AA and BB

Comment: @adamdms, In which case it wont bind, because the value of `Status` is either `Active` or `Disabled` which does not match `AA` or `BB` so the first option will selected (because something has to be selected). Why are you rendering the options `value` attribute as `AA` or `BB`? - it cannot bind in the view or when you post back

Comment: Some other functionality collects form fields and it need to get AA and BB. I have issue with rendering and selecting the right option. I wrote custom model binder, but it helps only to get the model in the controller. It doesn't select appropriate item.

Comment: Unless you write you own html helper, you are not going to have the correct item selected in the view because the value of `Status` is not either `AA` or `BB` (its `Active` or `Disabled`). Maybe using a view model with another enum containing `AA` and `BB` would make this a whole lot easier (no custom helper or model binder)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to the dropdown, create and populate `SelectList` manually and pass that and it will work:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListForEnum<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

    var items = Enum.GetNames(typeof(TEnum))
                .Select(n => (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), n))
                .Select(e => new 
                {
                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(e),
                    Text = e.ToString(),
                    Value = EnumExtension.GetValue(e).ToString(),
                    Selected = EnumExtension.GetValue(e) == EnumExtension.GetValue(metadata.Model)
                })
                .ToList();

    var selectList = new SelectList(items, "Text", "Value", selectedValue: items.Find(i => i.Selected).Text);
    return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList, htmlAttributes);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. You wrote names of the Text and Value properties in incorrect order. I need the AA and BB value to be in the value property.